# SQL batch variable

Tags: sql, batch-file, sqlcmd

I need to automate a query so I can perform it on all servers on a network. The thing is more servers are added constantly, so I need to keep it dynamic. On a table I have a list of the currently active servers, but they are repeated several times as each one has different data. Also it shows only a number, and the server name has an specific format. I did this to solve it:

```
select distinct ('swp0'+ cast(rtl_loc_id as nvarchar(4000)) +'r01') 
from basename..inv_valid_destinations
```

I got this to an output file, but now I want to use it as an input to sqlcmd. Each server name (each line from previous output) should be used as an -s argument. I have tried different ways of doing this to no avail. It should be something like this:

```
SQLCMD -Sswp0241r01 -Uswpos -isalto_folio.sql -osalto_folio.txt
```

As I said, more servers appear constantly and we need to perform a query on all active servers at the time and produce an output file. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this in batch you can use a loop, where `yourfile` is the file containing a list of servers.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (readme.txt) do (
    SQLCMD -S%%A -Uswpos -isalto_folio.sql -osalto_folio.txt
)
```

Comment: I only did an adjustment removing the "tokens=*" part, as it would not work with it. But it did what I needed, thank you very much.